# Writable Shared Memory in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working on a project of Twitter Data Analysis using Apache Spark with Java and Cassandra for NoSQL databases.

In the project I am working I want to maintain a arraylist of linkedlist(will use Java in built Arraylist and Linkedlist) which is common to all mapper nodes. I mean, if one mapper writes some data into arraylist it should be reflected to all other mapper nodes.

I am aware of broadcast shared variable, but that is read only shared variable, what I want is shared writable dataframe where changes by one mapper should be reflected in all.

Any advice on how to achieve this in apache spark with Java will be of great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure that this design really fits with Spark's distributed computing model, you're asking for shared memory across clusters of computers after all.

Answer (score 2):

Short, and most likely disappointing, answer is it is not possible given Spark architecture. Worker nodes don't communicate with each other and neither broadcast variables nor accumulators (write-only variables) are really shared variables. You can try different workarounds like using external services or shared file system to communicate but it introduces all kind of issues like idempotency or synchronizing.

As far as I can tell the best thing you can get is updating state between batches or using tools like `StreamingContext.remember`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try your suggestion and update once it is done.